# Trying to subtract from data in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a point of sale system, here is the interface;
[image]

I'm using Firebase Firestore as the database.
When items to be sold have been selected and paid for, it is sent to the database. I'm trying to subtract the quantity of the selected items from the total quantity of the item in the inventory data in the firestore database.

Here is the firestore database, the highlighted is the total quantity of an item which I'm trying to subtract from;
[image]

So far I tried iterating, using for loop, each item in the checkout data array getting the item ID and quantity. Then getting each item using the item ID (gotten earlier from checkout data) from firestore and subtract from the total quantity.

Here is the code of the for loop;

```
 for (let item in checkoutData) {

            let itemId = checkoutData[item].id;
            var checkoutQty = checkoutData[item].quantity;

            db.collection("inventories").where("productNumber", "==", itemId).get()
                .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                        var inventoryQty = parseInt(doc.data().productQuanity);

                        var sub = inventoryQty - checkoutQty;

                        console.log(`Subtract inventory qty from checkout qty for item ${doc.data().productNumber} = ${sub}`);

                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                });
        }
```

But when I ran this function, in the result its subtracting the quantity of the last item in the checkout data from the data in the inventory table in firestore database.

Here is the result;
[image]

In the image above, the highlighted is the quantity of the last item in the checkout data array being used to subtract the rest which is wrong.

What I'm trying to achieve is to subtract each item in the checkout data array from item in the ineventory data in firestore database using their unique item ID.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to subtract a quantity on your firestore database and it's not being reflected correctly?

Comment: yeah It's not subtracting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving your changes into Firestore, when you retrieve the data and subtract it you have to save back the record in order to keep it on Firestore. You can do that by using [set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) as shown here:

```
for (let item in checkoutData) {

        let itemId = checkoutData[item].id;
        var checkoutQty = checkoutData[item].quantity;

        db.collection("inventories").where("productNumber", "==", itemId).get()
          .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
              var inventoryQty = parseInt(doc.data().productQuanity);
              var sub = inventoryQty - checkoutQty;
              try {
                //set the quantity of the item
                let setInventoryQty = await db.collection("inventories").doc(doc.id).set({
                  productQuanity: sub,
                }, { merge: true });
              } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error while trying to set the quantity")
              }
              console.log(`Subtract inventory qty from checkout qty for item ${doc.data().productNumber} = ${sub}`);

            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
          });
      }
```

Please note that I'm using `merge: true` so it only overwrites the specific field